# Convert from String to Date with PHP

Tags: php, date, typeconverter

I have a String like that : `Sun Jul 21 02:51:39 +0000 2013` 
i want to convert it to a date with PHP, it's possible ??

Comment: you can simply use the date function of php.
<?php
echo date("Y/m/d");?>

Answer (score 0):

do it like that:

```
$arr = date_parse("Sun Jul 21 02:51:39 +0000 2013");
```

after that you can do something like this:

```
$unixTimestamp = mktime($arr["hour"], $arr["minute"], $arr["second"], $arr["month"], $arr["day"], $arr["year"]);
```

Comment: cool. mark some answer as correct answer please :)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use strtotime also. http://php.net/strtotime It works for older php versions also.